# Processwire, build own url route: /parent/child to /child

Tags: routes, processwire

Hello Fans of Processwire,

i search for an solution to change url-route of my own in Processwire.
This is my Template-structure in Processwire:

```
/categories (tpl_style_categories_parent.php)
    /cat1 (tpl_style_categories.php)
    /cat2 (tpl_style_categories.php)
```

the url for now is categories/cat1 but i want only /cat1 as url.
How can i make this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Best way to do this is by enabling [Url Segments](https://processwire.com/docs/tutorials/how-to-use-url-segments/) on the parent of tpl_style_categories_parent (not visible on the structure you provided) to capture the category name, and render the content of the corresponding page. Very simplified code on the template that page (the one that is not visible here):

```
if($input->urlSegment1) {

  $name = $sanitizer->name($input->urlSegment1);
  $category_page = $pages->get("template=tpl_style_categories, name={$name}");

  echo $category_page->render();

} else {

  // normal code for the template

}
```

Make sure to read everything in that link to know the best practices of using Url Segments

Comment: I enable Url Segment and add your code to the template. I try www.my-domain.de/cat1 instead of www.my-domain.de/category/cat1. But it doesn't work. In doku i found no way to do this. Can you help me please with some working example?

Comment: @chuebert maybe you could provide some more information, e.g. by updating your question to include more code examples what you tried so far..